# create linked list of ordered list without using object-oriented programming

Tags: vb.net, linked-list, record

the following code is supposed to output 6 4 3 as 3 4 6 when passed from main function. i need solution using following identifiers. i have found alternative object oriented solutions but i cant use null. and when i try to bring those concepts i cant use all the following identifiers. im so focused on the following code because this solution is provided on a-level computer science book in pseudocode form. 
i havent understood the necessity of identifier like `startpointer`

```
Dim nullPointer As Integer = -1

    'nullpointer should be set to -1 if using array element with index 0
    Public Structure ListNode
        Public Data As Integer
        Public Pointer As Integer
    End Structure
    'declare record type to store data and pointer


    Dim StartPointer As Integer
    Dim FreeListPtr As Integer
    Dim List(6) As ListNode
    Dim newItem As Integer
    Dim NewNodePtr As Integer
    Dim ThisNodePtr As Integer
    Dim previousNodePtr As Integer
```

```
Sub InitialiseList()
        StartPointer = nullPointer 'set start pointer
        FreeListPtr = 1            'set starting position of free list
        For index As Integer = 0 To 5 'link all nodes to make free list
            List(index).Pointer = index + 1
        Next
        List(6).Pointer = nullPointer 'last node of free list    
    End Sub
```

```
 Sub InsertNode(ByVal newItem)
        StartPointer = 0
        If FreeListPtr <> nullPointer Then 'there is space in the array
            'take node from free list and store data item
            NewNodePtr = FreeListPtr
            List(NewNodePtr).Data = newItem
            FreeListPtr = List(FreeListPtr).Pointer 'find insertion point
            ThisNodePtr = StartPointer 'start at beginning of list

            While ThisNodePtr <> nullPointer And List(ThisNodePtr).Data < newItem
                'while not end ofl list
                previousNodePtr = ThisNodePtr 'remember this node follow the pointer to the next node
                ThisNodePtr = List(ThisNodePtr).Pointer
            End While


            If previousNodePtr = StartPointer Then 'insert new node at start of list
                List(NewNodePtr).Pointer = StartPointer
                StartPointer = NewNodePtr
            Else 'insert new node between previous node and this node
                List(NewNodePtr).Pointer = List(previousNodePtr).Pointer
                List(previousNodePtr).Pointer = NewNodePtr
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

after i execute the code and see how my code run with the help of breakpoint on while statement. the loop run infinite at the third execution of the function.

```
 Dim currentnodeptr As Integer
Sub OutputAllNodes()
        StartPointer = 0
        currentnodeptr = StartPointer
        While currentnodeptr <> nullPointer
            console.writeline(list(currentnodeptr).data)
            currentnodeptr = List(currentnodeptr).Pointer
            currentnodeptr = currentnodeptr + 1
        End While

    End Sub
```

startpointer has to have 0 otherwise the problem arise since nullpointer was -1 and it will trigger error of indexoutofbound

```
Sub Main()
        InitialiseList()
        InsertNode(6)
        InsertNode(4)
        InsertNode(3)
        OutputAllNodes()
    End Sub
```

the output that i get is 0 and 6 on infinite time

Comment: .net provides a LinkedList(Of T). It might save you some code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Mary it is a built-in functionality form vb.net. i am trying to build one for research purposes. Furthermore it uses object oriented concept, here i am not supposed to.

Comment: ` Sub InsertNode(ByVal newItem)` newItem needs a datatype. I assume it is an Integer. Yes?

Comment: yes, it is @Mary

Comment: `NewNodePtr` is not declared. Neither is `ThisNodePtr` nor `previousNodePtr`. Please correct you code to declare these variables.

Comment: @Mary ok i just did. i forgot to submit them i had them on my ide. sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204796/discussion-between-saugat-thapa-and-mary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you fix your endless loop, all will be well.

```
Sub OutputAllNodes()
    StartPointer = 0
    currentnodeptr = StartPointer
    'While currentnodeptr <> nullPointer
    '    Console.WriteLine(List(currentnodeptr).Data)
    '    currentnodeptr = List(currentnodeptr).Pointer
    '    currentnodeptr = currentnodeptr + 1
    'End While
    For Each item In List
        Console.WriteLine($"Data {item.Data}, Pointer {item.Pointer}")
    Next
End Sub
```

In the InsertNode Sub rem out the following

```
        'If previousNodePtr = StartPointer Then 'insert new node at start of list
        '    'List(NewNodePtr).Pointer = StartPointer 'Don't reset the pointer
        '    StartPointer = NewNodePtr
        'Else 'insert new node between previous node and this node
        '    List(NewNodePtr).Pointer = List(previousNodePtr).Pointer
        '    List(previousNodePtr).Pointer = NewNodePtr
        'End If
```

My output

```
Data 0, Pointer 1
Data 6, Pointer 2
Data 4, Pointer 3
Data 3, Pointer 4
Data 0, Pointer 5
Data 0, Pointer 6
Data 0, Pointer -1
```

**EDIT**

```
Public Structure ListNode
    Public Data As Integer
    Public Pointer As Integer
End Structure

Private CurrentIndex As Integer
Private NodeList(6) As ListNode 'Seven elements in the array

Sub Main()
    InitialiseList()
    InsertNode(6)
    InsertNode(4)
    InsertNode(3)
    OutputAllNodes()
End Sub

Private Sub InsertNode(input As Integer)
    NodeList(CurrentIndex).Data = input
    CurrentIndex += 1
End Sub

Sub InitialiseList()
    For index As Integer = 0 To 5 'link all nodes to make free list
        NodeList(index).Pointer = index + 1
    Next
    NodeList(6).Pointer = -1 'last node of free list  
End Sub

Sub OutputAllNodes()
    For Each item In NodeList
        Console.WriteLine($"Data {item.Data}, Pointer {item.Pointer}")
    Next
End Sub
```

Output

```
Data 6, Pointer 1
Data 4, Pointer 2
Data 3, Pointer 3
Data 0, Pointer 4
Data 0, Pointer 5
Data 0, Pointer 6
Data 0, Pointer -1
```

Comment: because in `InitialiseList` you set `FreeListPtr = 1` Then in`InsertNode` you `NewNodePtr = FreeListPtr` and 
            `List(NewNodePtr).Data = newItem` so the index of the first insert is one.

Comment: also the expected output is 3 4 6 not 6 4 3. if i provide 8 5 6 will i get 8  6 5? because i need the output sorted(ordered).

Comment: See my edit. It depends on the order you add the elements. You can sort an array but that is the subject of another question.

Comment: i need the ordering portion too. in your view, does the code perform sorting in any ways? does order and sort mean same thing? because i thought while loop would help doing so

Comment: No, no sorting. Order and Sort depend on the context.

Comment: what would have been the solution to the problem arised from not setting startpointer to 0 in insertnode and not rem out the lines u told to rem out? i also need to get third element's pointer to nullpointer i.e. -1 and last element also nullpointer(which i already have). would i ever be able to achieve it? that way i wouldnt have needed to change the loop of outputallnodes() sub: just a thought!